# Why don't we add the exclude option in filtering?

Tags: website-design, filter, tags, tag-hierarchy

I have come across the necessity of this option lately and feel like people can use this for improvising the UX of the filtering process.

Example:
Let's say I'm searching for a UX Internship and would love to look for opportunities in Europe.

Now, I am not so enthusiastic to work in certain European Countries though. I had a few listings from such companies. The work was of my interest but the place was not(Various reasons).
I didn’t want to see such listings anymore.[image: Set A]

What if I could do this while filtering?
[image: Set B]

Set A- Include Query

Set B- Exclude Query

The user is shown results from Set A-Set B.

This problem is omnipotent!

Is this good?

*all countries are equally lovely, just for representation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on implementing exactly this kind of feature: filter a list of people based on tags, with the possibility to either include or exclude any tag.

I reviewed a number of existing UI solutions, and the best UX I found is this one: https://help.highrisehq.com/contacts/better-tags/

I'm going to test a similar design in the coming weeks. I will share the results here.

The other examples I found would allow either to include or exclude, but not both. 
Another idea I came up with was to allow the user to add tags to either one of 2 lists: tags to include, tags to leave out, but it appeared to be confusing for users.

Comment: Hey!
Great to know you are implementing this! Do share the results as promised.
This can actually bring about a change i believe.